# Error in c program in printf because of %

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am writing my first c Program in Visual studio and getting very basic error because of the format specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    int area = x*y;
    printf("Enter the value of x  \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter the value of y  \n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

    printf("Area of the rectangle is %d\n", area);
    return 0;
}
```

error:
Enter the value of x
2
Enter the value of y
1
Area of the rectangle is -293795784 // This is the error. I am expecting for Output 2 i.e product of x and y
Not sure why its taking the address of the value instead of value.

Comment: The instructions are executed _sequencially_.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: C does not work like a spreadsheet, where all the cells are interrelated. It only knows the values that have already been assigned. What you have done with `int area = x*y;` is *undefined behaviour* because `int x,y;` has no initialisation of the values.

Comment: This isn't a spreadsheet, nor a VHDL or something, When you type that `int area = x*y;` you aren't hooking up wires into some async logic gates circuitry, this actually translates into sequentially running CPU instructions, and takes whatever happened to be in `x` and `y` at that moment, multiplies it, and loads the result into `area`. And thats exactly what ends up being printed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can not find the area before x and y are initialised!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y;

    printf("Enter the value of x  \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter the value of y  \n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    //Put this area formula here
    int area = x*y;
    printf("Area of the rectangle is %d\n", area);

    return 0;

}
```

Also you need to check the return value from `scanf`. That is - check that `scanf` actually scanned an integer. In other words: When you want to read exactly 1 integer, check that `scanf` returns 1. If not, there is an error.

This goes like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y;

    printf("Enter the value of x  \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)            // Notice this line
    {
        // Wrong input - stop program
        fprintf(stderr,"Input error - input must be a number\n");
        exit(1);
    };

    printf("Enter the value of y  \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &y) != 1)            // Notice this line
    {
        // Wrong input - stop program
        fprintf(stderr,"Input error - input must be a number\n");
        exit(1);
    };
    
    //Put this area formula here
    int area = x*y;
    printf("Area of the rectangle is %d\n", area);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the variable area before taking the input of x and y instead you should also assign a value for your area variable which is x*y.

what you did

```
int x,y;
int area= x*y; // you dont have the value of x and y yet //
```

so after that, if you print the value of area it actually doesn't have any value.

what you should do assigning the value of area after you have the value of x and y.

The correct way

```
int x,y;

printf("Enter the value of x  \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Enter the value of y  \n");
    scanf("%d", &y);

int area=x*y; // now you have the value of x & y //
```

Answer (score -1):

I fight with IDE all the time because I like spaces and blank lines but no line waste.  I stand off operands, operators most places.  I like to NOT bury the lead on if or while of call returns, either:

```
printf("Enter the value of x: ");

while ( 1 != scanf( "%d", &x )){
    fprintf( stderr, "Invalid x input, must be a number!\n" );
}

printf("Enter the value of y: ");

while ( 1 != scanf( "%d", &x )){
    fprintf( stderr, "Invalid y input, must be a number!\n" );
}
```

This reduces eyestrain for all, makes errors easier to see, improves grades and the boss's opinion, conserves vertical white space.  I stack one liners but stand off all blocks.  I do the {} always in case I want to add lines, like debug printouts.  I say 'else' rarely, preferring to exit(), return, break, continue or use the ternary operator, in parentheses for operator precedence: ( <boolean_value> ? <true_value> : <false_value> ).  I try to use switch whenever possible for more than 2 outcomes, as it is a wonderful place to hang comments, like SQL CASE, with no extra indent for cases!

```
int retries = 0, ret ;
char buf[4096];

do {
    switch ( ret = read( fd, buf, sizeof( buf ))){
    case -1: // report error
        perror( "read(fd)" );
        exit( 1 );
    case 0: // nominal EOF; sockets, pipes return 0 for 0 length messages.
        if ( ++retries > 100 ){
            return 0 ; // assume normal EOF behavior for some function
        }

        continue ;
    default: // we read something
        retries = 0 ;
        break;
    }
} while ( ! ret );

// process the read() data
```

Of course, opinions vary!  :D

Comment: How might this answer the question?

Comment: Proper way to do user input.

Comment: True, but there is no question about user input. And formatting preferences are even more off.

Comment: I did not put formatting on the table, I just chimed in.  I hope some IDE people rethink what beautified C/C++/C#/JAVA looks like.  I had to use 'answer' as 'comment' destroys formatting.